Предупреждение при чтении CSV файла Undefined array key 1
Всем привет! Изучаю библиотеку PHP-ML.
Постоянно возникает предупреждение при чтении CSV файла

Warning: Undefined array key 1 in
C:\OSPanel\domains\curs.loc\vendor\php-ai\php-ml\src\Phpml\Dataset\CsvDataset.php
on line 42

код полностью брал из примера, проблем возникать как бы не должно
<?php

namespace PhpmlExercise;

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Phpml\Classification\NaiveBayes;
use Phpml\Dataset\CsvDataset;

use Phpml\FeatureExtraction\TokenCountVectorizer;
use Phpml\Tokenization\WordTokenizer;
use Phpml\FeatureExtraction\TfIdfTransformer;

use Phpml\Dataset\ArrayDataset;
use Phpml\CrossValidation\StratifiedRandomSplit;

use Phpml\Metric\Accuracy;

// Step 1: Load the Dataset
$dataset = new CsvDataset('C:\ospanel\domains\curs.loc\data_teach\clean_tweets.csv', 1, true);

$samples = [];
foreach ($dataset->getSamples() as $sample) {
    $samples[] = $sample[0];
}

// Step 2: Prepare the Dataset
$vectorizer = new TokenCountVectorizer(new WordTokenizer());
$vectorizer->fit($samples);
$vectorizer->transform($samples);

$tfIdfTransformer = new TfIdfTransformer();
$tfIdfTransformer->fit($samples);
$tfIdfTransformer->transform($samples);

Код, на который ссылается предупреждение:
public function __construct(string $filepath, int $features, bool $headingRow = true)
    {
        if (!file_exists($filepath)) {
            throw FileException::missingFile(basename($filepath));
        }

        if (false === $handle = fopen($filepath, 'rb')) {
            throw FileException::cantOpenFile(basename($filepath));
        }

        if ($headingRow) {
            $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',');
            $this->columnNames = array_slice($data, 0, $features);
        } else {
            $this->columnNames = range(0, $features - 1);
        }

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== false) {
            $this->samples[] = array_slice($data, 0, $features);
            $this->targets[] = $data[$features];  //предупреждение здесь
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

Сам csv файл


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Перед тем как изучать библиотеку PHP-ML, необходимо изучить основы языка РНР. В частности работу с массивами. И уяснив, в каком случае появляется эта ошибка, обратить внимание на содержимое файла. Из каждой ли его строки можно получить три элемента

Да, эту ошибку уже заметил, при создании класса, должно быть указано 1, а не 2
В этом случае сообщение просто изменяется на "Undefined array key 1"

Возьмите отладку  посмотрите пошагово что у вас в коде происходит и придите к какому-либо выводу.

Тут и без отладки видно. @ЛогиновДенисАлексеевич, Перед тем как изучать библиотеку PHP-ML, необходимо изучить основы языка РНР. В частности работу с массивами. И уяснив, в каком случае появляется эта ошибка, обратить внимание на содержимое файла. Из каждой ли его строки можно получить два элемента
